# Remove empty list item after all items are deleted

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

[image]When I delete items from a list in Angular 2 everything works perfectly until I delete the last item in the list. When I delete the last item the content is deleted and removed form the DB, this is correct but I am left with an empty UI component for the list when what should happen is the list should just look completely empty like it did before I added any items in the first place.

Edit: 
See the remaining stub in the goals list after I have deleted all the goals.

Goals.component

```
// Get Goals for Team
      this.goals$ = this.teamsService.getAllGoalsForTeam(this.team.slug);

<goal-item [goals]="goals$ | async"></goal-item>
```

Goal-item.component

```
<div class="col-xs-4 goal-container" *ngFor="let goal of goals">
   #Goal structure here
</div>
```

Delete function

```
delete(goal){
    this.goalsService.deleteGoal(goal);
  }
```

Goals.service

```
// Delete Goal

      deleteGoal(goal) {
        this.af.database.object('goals/' +  goal.$key).remove();
      }
```

Comment: What is the question you are asking?  You are describing a fairly straightforward HTML design, but it's not really clear why you aren't getting what you expect, since you haven't shown any code.

Comment: Please post the code you got for the list

Comment: updated, added image to show what I mean by remaining stub after deletion

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, you wont be able to nullify the first position in a node. If you want it to be already handled then i would suggest using a library like [angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) .Otherwise, If you want to handle it yourself :

```
//In the Component : 
<div class="col-xs-4 goal-container" *ngFor="let goal of goals">
   <div *ngIf="checkForData(goal)">
   #Goal structure here
   </div>
</div>

//In you .ts file : 

checkForData(goal){
   //logic to check if the object has any data;
   //returns true or false
}
```

EDIT :: Change the div structure like so :

```
<div *ngFor="let goal of goals">
<div class="col-xs-4 goal-container" *ngIf="checkForData(goal)">
   <div>
   #Goal structure here
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using angularfire but that still doesn't clear the empty stub in the loop

Comment: @Daimz Check the EDIT section

Answer (score 0):

you can use *ngIf in this case

```
<div class="col-xs-4 goal-container" *ngFor="let goal of goals" *ngIf="goals.length >0">
   #Goal structure here
</div>
```

so when list will empty div will get removed from view.

Comment: You can't use a *ngFor and *ngIf on the same element, Angular only allows you to use 1 structural directive or you will get an error. That said even wrapping the goal container in `<ng-container *ngIf="goals.length > 0">` does not work it still shows the empty stub.